# uwp app only accepts input whenever i have opened on conhost/powershell/cmd

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

As the title says, i can only input data into the text box whenever i have conhost/powershell/cmd opened and its the first window (not covered by anything and is focused). why would that be and its not a code problem because my friend does not have said issue and we both are working on the same application. Please help.

This has had happen on my previous windows install so i reinstalled and it is still happening (it happened on my previous computer too since then i have switched computers)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.